# Remove function argument after setting it to a value with functools.partial

Tags: python, lambda, functools, function-signature

I would like to use `functools.partial` to set a certain argument to a constant and at the same time remove the argument altogether.

Let me explain it using a simple example.

```
from functools import partial
def f(a, b):
    return a * b

g = partial(f, b=2)
```

However, this function `g` still has the following calling signature:

```
g?

Signature:      g(a, *, b=1)
Call signature: g(*args, **kwargs)
Type:           partial
String form:    functools.partial(<function f at 0x7ff7045289d8>, b=1)
File:           /opt/conda/envs/dev/lib/python3.6/functools.py
Docstring:     
partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application
of the given arguments and keywords.
```

I could of course do this with a lambda function like:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a * b

g = lambda a: f(a, b=2)
```

with the correct calling signature:

```
g?

Signature: g(a)
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      ~/Work/<ipython-input-7-fc5f3f492590>
Type:      function
```

The downside of using `lamdba` functions is that I would need to write down all the arguments again. In my simple example this doesn't matter, but look at this:

```
phase_func = lambda site1, site2, B_x, B_y, B_z, orbital, e, hbar: \
    phase_func(site1, site2, B_x, B_y, B_z, orbital, e, hbar, xyz_offset=(0,0,0))
# or this
phase_func = partial(phase_func, xyz_offset=(0,0,0)
```

## Why would I even want this?

Later in my code I use wrappers that can generate a new function by multiplying two other functions, like `combine(function1, function2, operator.mul)`. This `combine` function looks at all the arguments, therefore I need to remove the argument after setting it.

Comment: Then use the `lambda`, or make sure `combine` sets the appropriate default values. BTW I see `Signature:      g(a, *, b=2)` as per your `partial` call.

Comment: Have you confirmed this is an actual problem? The 'signature' you see is `inspect.signature` *special-casing `partial` objects*. If `combine()` does *not* use `inspect.signature()` then you should not actually see this issue.

Comment: If you wrote `combine()`, then the better solution is to detect signatures differently.